# Can't program ATtiny2313a with Arduino. Is my chip bricked?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, avr

I've been trying to burn a program into ATtiny2313A-PU with my [Arduino Uno](https://docs.arduino.cc/hardware/uno-rev3) R3 used as a programmer.

First I tried to program it from Arduino IDE 1.0.1 (Windows 7) and it seemed to upload the sketch, but the blink program didn't work.
Then I found [Michael Holachek's tutorial](http://michael.holachek.com/2012/09/avr-programming/) and followed his instructions:

1. uploaded the [ArduinoISP sketch](https://docs.arduino.cc/built-in-examples/arduino-isp/ArduinoISP) to my Arduino Uno
2. wired the circuit on a breadboard
3. installed [WinAVR](https://sourceforge.net/projects/winavr/) on my Windows 7.
4. downloaded Michael's template files (Makefile and main.c) and edited Makefile to match my settings (external 8 MHz crystal). I used [this online fuse calculator](http://www.engbedded.com/fusecalc/) to get correct fuse parameters.
5. then, in cmd.exe, changed directory to the directory where I saved Makefile and main.c and ran 'make flash'

#### Makefile

```
DEVICE     = attiny2313a
CLOCK      = 8000000
PROGRAMMER = -c arduino -P COM5 -b 19200
OBJECTS    = main.o
FUSES      = -U lfuse:w:0x5e:m -U hfuse:w:0xdd:m -U efuse:w:0xff:m


######################################################################
######################################################################

# Tune the lines below only if you know what you are doing:

AVRDUDE = avrdude $(PROGRAMMER) -p $(DEVICE)
COMPILE = avr-gcc -Wall -Os -DF_CPU=$(CLOCK) -mmcu=$(DEVICE)

# Symbolic targets:
all:    main.hex

.c.o:
    $(COMPILE) -c $< -o $@

.S.o:
    $(COMPILE) -x assembler-with-cpp -c $< -o $@
# "-x assembler-with-cpp" should not be necessary since this is the default
# file type for the .S (with capital S) extension. However, upper case
# characters are not always preserved on Windows. To ensure WinAVR
# compatibility define the file type manually.

.c.s:
    $(COMPILE) -S $< -o $@

flash:    all
    $(AVRDUDE) -U flash:w:main.hex:i

fuse:
    $(AVRDUDE) $(FUSES)

install: flash fuse

# If you use a bootloader, change the command below appropriately:
load: all
    bootloadHID main.hex

clean:
    rm -f main.hex main.elf $(OBJECTS)

# File targets:
main.elf: $(OBJECTS)
    $(COMPILE) -o main.elf $(OBJECTS)

main.hex: main.elf
    rm -f main.hex
    avr-objcopy -j .text -j .data -O ihex main.elf main.hex
# If you have an EEPROM section, you must also create a hex file for the
# EEPROM and add it to the "flash" target.

# Targets for code debugging and analysis:
disasm:    main.elf
    avr-objdump -d main.elf

cpp:
    $(COMPILE) -E main.c
```

#### File *main.c*

[image: main.c]

Below is the output I got:

```
C:\Users> cd /D D:\electronics

D:\electronics> cd nikon/mi

D:\electronics\nikon\mi> make flash

avr-gcc -Wall -Os -DF_CPU=8000000 -mmcu=attiny2313a -c main.c -o main.o
main.c:6: error: stray '\342' in program
main.c:6: error: stray '\200' in program
main.c:6: error: stray '\250' in program
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:9: error: stray '\342' in program
main.c:9: error: stray '\200' in program
main.c:9: error: stray '\250' in program
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

I suspect that I might brick the fuses on ATtiny2313a. If that is the case, I think I will have to build [this AVR rescue shield](http://mightyohm.com/blog/products/hv-rescue-shield-2-x/).
Maybe the Makefile was configured incorrectly?
How can I identify the problem? How can I check whether the chip is still alive?

Comment: I don't see how a compiler error would have any relation to the chip being broken. Your code is broken instead.

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken (it redirects to a generic page. And it seems to be completely empty).

Comment: A direct analysis is: 342 200 250 (octal) → 0xE2 0x80 0xA8 (hexadecimal) → UTF-8 sequence for Unicode code point U+2028 ([LINE SEPARATOR](https://www.charset.org/utf-8/9)). LINE SEPARATOR is probably some representation of return/newline. The code was probably copied from the (now broken) web page.

Comment: This is a ***very*** common error when copying code from web pages, [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) documents, through chat (e.g. [Skype Chat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_of_Skype#Skype_chat) or [Facebook Messenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Messenger)), etc. The canonical question is *[Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332)*.

Comment: There are really two questions here. The stray character problem (resulting in the reported errors) and the rest (e.g., the title). It really ought to be two separate questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332/compilation-error-stray-302-in-program-etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting compile errors there. I would check the contents of main.c for what the compiler is telling you to check. It looks like in the copy and paste of the code, something was lost. Also

```
PORTD ^= (1 << PD6);  // toggle PD6
```

can be replaced with

```
PIND = (1 << PD6);   // or _BV(PD6), since you should be using avr-libc anyway.
```

as per Atmel's datasheets.

Comment: You are right, TRON. I found two strange characters in main.c (like unicode medium square symbol). I think they didn't let me copy the code of main.c to this forum correctly. I just could not get the right formatting. That's why the code wasn't added to my original question.

Comment: I will add a screenshot of main.c to the original post now.
So, after those two characters were removed, the output changed very much. Now it seems to work, but there's another problem - avrdude can't find my chip 2313a in its configuration file.
`avrdude: AVR Part "attiny2313a" not found.`
I guess I will need to edit avrdude.conf. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I googled a little bit more and found that the most common solution, when chips are identical, but have different suffixes (like ATtiny2313 and ATtiny2313a) is to use -F key for overriding the signature check.

So, I added the key in Makefile `DEVICE     = attiny2313 -F` and my ATtiny2313a was programmed successfully!